# Add an error class to a chosen.js element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using the following html + php:

```
<select class="chosen <?php echo (isset($error) ? 'error' : ''); ?>">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('.chosen').chosen({width:"100%"});
```

And the css:

```
.error{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

I want to be able to add an error class to the chosen element, so that it becomes red. The problem is, it does not work. The chosen element stays the same (no red border).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any error messages in browser JS-console?

Comment: When you inspect the element via your browser's web developer tools does the `<select>` element have the `error` class-name, or is it the PHP that's not working?

Comment: @rt2800 no error messages

Comment: @david thomas the PHP code is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that chosen edits the HTML elements and what was once a select becomes a custom div. What you can do is get the div with the '.chosen-container' class and apply your styles there.

```js
$('.chosen').chosen();
```

```css
.chosen-container{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

select{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="chosen">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

If you still wanna use the php to echo the error class you can use jQuery as a workaround to apply the style, this way if you echo the class 'error' on the select the jQuery will apply it to the div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if($('select.chosen').hasClass('error')) {
            $('.chosen-container').addClass('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: but then the chosen element always has a red border. I only want a red border when the class "error" is applied (eg. when $error exists).